# Screen Flickering with Radeon 3000 Intgreted Graphics on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I have installed Linux on my custom built PC with a ASUS M5A78L-M Plus USB 3 Motherboard and it has AMD Radeon 3000 integrated graphics. Most applications display fine, except scrolling is jerky at times and videos saved to my hard drive are almost unplayable with a low frame rate and constant "white line flickering" on the screen. This system is dual-booted with Windows, where videos play fine. I've tried to install the AMD-GPU driver and the AMD-GPUpro driver but I believe they do not support my integrated graphics? I am using the Radeon driver.

I am new to Linux, but I am comfortable with the terminal and editing files with nano, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks
Chance

**EDIT: I am also experiencing issues when playing back online videos such as YouTube, but it's only issues with jerky movements and not really the FPS (if that makes since).**

Here is the output of sudo lshw -C display; lsb_release -a; and uname -a

This is the output of the first command:

*-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RS780L [Radeon 3000]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe8f0000-fe8fffff memory:fe700000-fe7fffff memory:c0000-dffff

This is the output of the second command:

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

And this is the output of the third command:

Linux Chance-Ubuntu 5.4.0-29-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 14:32:27 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried following the instructions from several other questions on this page, but none of them seem to work. Please Help!